# Using different data transformation in ensembles

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning, stacking, voting-system

I have trained few models using sklearn and python. However I have scaled the data for **Support Vector Machines - standarized** and for **Neural Network - Scaled [0-1]** since it gives me better results and I believe it should be like that.

Since the ensembles usually gives better results than weak classifiers I would like to take advantage of that. I can train the SVM on standarized data and that's fine. But when i feed ensemble, let's say **Stacking** or **Voting** I'm just passing the non-scaled data because there are many other models and the models do not need scaled data.

I have struggled using pipeline. How do you handle such a problem?